# Is there a way to use `pytest-snapshot` with unsortable list?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, snapshot

I want to implement a test that looks like this :

```py
def test_some_function(snapshot):

        my_unsortable_list = my_function()

        assert my_unsortable_list == snapshot
```

- However the `my_unsortable_list` variable is of type `List[Dict]` and there is no easy way to sort it.
- Also, the values inside `my_unsortable_list` are always the same but the order is random.
- Therefore the assertion `assert my_unsortable_list == snapshot` fails if we run this test.

I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of snapshot order and do something like this :

```py
assert len(my_unsortable_list) == len(snapshot) # Compare number of elements in lists
assert all([x in my_unsortable_list for x in snapshot]) # Assert all elements are in both lists
```

The code above fails, is there a way to use advanced features of pytest-snapshot so that works ?

Comment: `snapshot` only tests strings or bytes, if your list is unsortable it probably has other things in it. You can use `pickle` to write to a file, and then read back in the test and confirm they are the same. But if your list is unsortable that might not work either.